# How to create a Hive table with multiple hdfs files

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, hdfs

So basically I would like to create a table containing csv files

I tried something like this where the filenames only differ from eachother by the two last digits :

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE pageviews
>    (page_date string,site string)
>   ROW FORMAT
>                 DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
>                 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
>                 STORED AS TEXTFILE
>                 LOCATION '/user/hue/201401/pageviews/supersite_1046_201401**.csv';

To me this syntax looks ok  but when I execute it I get the following:

> Error occurred executing hive query: Unknown exception.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I doubt if it can accept wildcards in textfile location.

Comment: That is indeed one of my points of concern but I have no clue how to do it without using a wildcard.

Comment: This is a suggestion. Can you try providing path only upto the folder name (Assuming the folder will contain only the necessary files).

Comment: it does indeed only contain the necessary files yet I get the same unknown exception error.

To give u an idea the folder contains out of 17 identical constructed csv files.

Comment: Just use the directory as the location argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `LOCATION` parameter of a hive's `create table` statement takes as argument a *hdfs_path* ([See here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/TruncateTable)). Such a path cannot be file path, but must be a directory path, hence the error you get.

In your case, you could put the required files under a specific directory und specify this very directory in the LOCATION clause of the create table statement.